# Simplify segment conditional documentation

Tags: conditionals, segments

Exist an interesting method to simplify a multiple conditional:

If you want to execute the code when url_title not equal to "portfolio" neither equal to "photos" use this condition:

```
{if segment_2 != "portfolio" && segment_2 != "photos"}
    <p>Conditional content.</p>
{/if}
```

Or as a simple way:

```
{if ! "portfolio|photos" *= segment_2}
    I am here
{/if}
```

It works fine, does exist a documentation for this pattern:

```
segment_2 != "portfolio" && segment_2 != "photos"
```

to

```
! "portfolio|photos" *= segment_2  ?
```

I didn't find it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The conditional operators that work in [EE are listed in the documentation](https://docs.expressionengine.com/latest/templates/conditionals.html#operators).

The two conditional forms you talk about are not equivalent, they just happen to give the same outputs for the inputs you describe.

The first form (with the `&&` in it) only fires if the url_title is not `portfolio` and also not `photos`.  So if you tested the url_title `hot` with this conditional it would return TRUE (since `hot` is neither `portfolio` nor `photos`).

The `*=` term in second form tests to see if the the content of first term (in your example the string `portfolio|photos` contains the value in segment_2.  When you add the negative operator (`!`) this returns TRUE only if the content of segment_2 is not contained within the string.  This is similar in function to the first conditional but not the same: it will return "FALSE" for any circumstance where the content of segment_2 is found in your string - so not only for the url_titles `portfolio` and `photos` but also `hot`, `folio` and `port` (and many more).

So while the first conditional only looks for the two terms specified, the second looks for any combination of letters that might appear within the conjoined strings you have used.  Which means the second conditional is not a simplification of the first, it is different to the first but under some conditions provides similar outputs.

HTH

Comment: Hi JCOGS, thanks for your response. Really I already read many times the doc, and I never saw the *= term. It's a nice solution to simplify complex conditionals.

Comment: Why is the negative operator (NOT) not listed on this page of the documentation?  eg
{if !logged_in}...{/if}

Comment: The NOT operator is listed in the documentation under Logical Operators - here: https://docs.expressionengine.com/latest/templates/conditionals.html#logical-operators.  You would have seen it if you had thought to scroll down the page a bit.

Comment: True, thanks... but no example of what would be a pretty common shorthand use case. A better case might be {if !segment_3}...{/if}